# Debug Angular application POST requests

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, angular6

I have Angular application with login form which is connected to standalone Spring app.

I edited my Spring code to be deployable in Wildfly server. But when I start the Angular application and I try to send requests I see only into the console:

[HPM] POST /api/oauth/token -> http://localhost:8080

There are no errors. How I can find the issue? I suppose that my Application start method is not correct and web services aren to running:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "org.admin.*", "org.plugin.service" })
@EntityScan("org.datalis.plugin.entity")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

IN log file I can see that end point is registered:

```
2018-10-08 12:32:19,060 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.get(java.lang.String)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,061 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions/{id}],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.save(java.lang.String,org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PaymentTransactionsDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,064 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.create(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PaymentTransactionsDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,065 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.data.domain.Page<org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PaymentTransactionsDTO> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.find(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PaymentTransactionsFilterDTO,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,069 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions/export],methods=[GET]}" onto public void org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.export(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,073 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions/types],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.getTypes()
2018-10-08 12:32:19,078 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/users/reset],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.UserController.reset(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PasswordResetDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,079 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/users/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.UserController.token(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PasswordResetDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,080 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/users/request],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.UserController.resetRequest(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PasswordResetDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,092 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,093 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

Comment: Is the list of the mapped endpoints you posted complete? Because it does not contain the endpoint you are trying to make a request to.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Let me check

Comment: Can you please show your controller for /api/oauth/token ?